# Python exit handlers

Tags: python, process, exit

I'm a bit confused by the many different ways to install exit handlers in Python applications. There's [`atexit.register()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) and [`signal.signal(SIG, handler)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#example), but I'm unsure which one is the right to use in my case.

I've got a main process started from the command line which spawns a number of other sub processes as daemons. It then `join`s the processes and waits until they finish. The sub processes run an infinite loop (can break out by a flag, but not sure how to trigger that). I'd like to call some cleanup code in the sub processes when the main process gets either shut down via CTRL+C or when it receives a kill signal.

What's the best way of achieving this, given the 2 exit handler methods (or perhaps there're more).

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of `atexit`:

> Functions thus registered are automatically executed upon normal interpreter termination.

and

> Note: The functions registered via this module are not called when the program is killed by a signal not handled by Python, when a Python fatal internal error is detected, or when os._exit() is called.

So if you want to react to signals, use `signal.signal`.

Comment: Would it work to `sys.exit()` in the signal hook and leave the cleaup to `atexit`? Shouldn't this cater for all cases (normal exit and forced exit)? How can I catch `SIGKILL` (if at all)?